# Get closest element from array

Tags: swift

i have an integer and an array. What i want to do is to search in the array the closest number to that integer, but only for bigger values.
Ex
let number = 2
array = [1,4,5,6]

the result should be 4

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your array always in ascending order?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assumption, array is sorted in ascending order or you can sort before performing this task in function below.
Here is solution.

```
let array = [1, 4, 5, 6]

func findClosestBiggerValue(number: Int) -> Int? {
    for item in array {
        if item > number {
            return item
        }
    }
    return nil // Nothing found
}

                            // returns 4
if let closestBiggerValue = findClosestBiggerValue(number: 2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Returning -1 (magic numbers) it is definitely not recommended. What's wrong with returning an optional integer (nil) ?

Comment: @LeoDabus your are right, nil is the power of swift. Lemme edit this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use first where method and pass a predicate. Of course this assumes your array is always in ascending order:

```
let array = [1, 4, 5, 6]
let number = 2
let result = array.first(where: {$0 > number})
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
array
  .lazy
  .filter { $0 > number }
  .min()
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried a different way. Added a number to the array successfully. The array then sorted and the index was found. I think the answer you want is index plus 1.

```swift
var array = [1, 4, 5, 6]
let number = 2
array.insert(number, at: 0)
array.sort()

if let firstIndex = array.firstIndex(of: number) {
    print("index: \(firstIndex+1), value: \(array[firstIndex+1])")
}
```